# MYSQL: How to call a function in a table alias field

Tags: mysql

i don't know if i'm not searching for this solution with the proper description of the problem, but i've not been able to find the answer for my situation.

Basically i have a table that i'm going to self join, so for that i use an Alias for this table (T1). In this table i have a datetime field and i want to extract only the year with the year function like this:

```
SELECT t1.item,
t1.quantity,
t1.time_in,
t1.YEAR(time_in) AS year
FROM rec AS t1
```

But i get the following error: FUNCTION t1.YEAR does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

I tried to use backticks for the table alias like this 't1'.YEAR(time_in), but this didn't work either.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Table names/aliases go before column names, not before functions.

```
SELECT t1.item,
    t1.quantity,
    t1.time_in,
    YEAR(t1.time_in) AS year
FROM rec AS t1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really screwed it up, hehe